# Razor view not creating after adding reference of project in .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

When I add a reference to the class library project and try to add a new view it's not making. visual studio is giving me an error.
I am working on.net 6.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGXWi.png)

Comment: It is a [know issue](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/2019), You can try to update your `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package to the newest version and try again.

Comment: Thank you. Updating Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package from 6.0.9 to 6.0.10 its work.